# React hooks performance when providing a callback without a stale closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm puzzled as to how make a performant component with React hooks when it accepts a callback that depend on a state variable of a parent component which the child need to update.

In particular, let's imagine the scenario where we have a very long list of items that the user can select with a checkbox. Simply the parent component renders "Selected {x} items". It has to hold the state with all of the items and as to if they are checked or not and therefore also provide a callback to the child to be able to toggle.

The requirement is for the child components to *only* re-render when the checked property actually change. Otherwise do *not* re-render. This is fairly easy with a class component:

```js
class ItemList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        items: [
        { id: 1, text: "Item 1", checked: false },
        { id: 2, text: "Item 2", checked: false },
      ],
    }
    
    this.toggleChecked = this.toggleChecked.bind(this)
  }
  
  toggleChecked(itemId) {
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.map(i => ({
        ...i,
        ...(i.id === itemId && {checked: !i.checked})
      }))
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>
          Selected {this.state.items.filter(i => i.checked).length} items
        </h2>
        <ol>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <Item 
            {...item}
            key={item.id} 
            onChange={this.toggleChecked}
          />
        ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Item extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
    console.log(`Rendering item ${this.props.id}`)
    return (
        <li>
        <label>
          <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            checked={this.props.checked} 
            onChange={() => this.props.onChange(this.props.id)}
          /> 
          <span>{this.props.text}</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    )
  }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render(<ItemList />)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65Lpo80v/34/

When clicking on the first item we can see in the console that only the first item renders, the same for the second. Great!

Now trying to do the same with hooks is impossible I think! Let's see the first iteration of my code:

```js
const ItemList = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, text: "Item 1", checked: false },
    { id: 2, text: "Item 2", checked: false },
  ])
  
  const toggleChecked = React.useCallback((itemId) => {
    setItems(items.map(i => ({
        ...i,
        ...(i.id === itemId && {checked: !i.checked})
      }))
    )
  }, [items])
  

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        Selected {items.filter(i => i.checked).length} items
      </h2>
      <ol>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item 
          {...item}
          key={item.id} 
          onChange={toggleChecked}
        />
      ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
  )

}

const Item = React.memo(({id, text, checked, onChange}) => {
  console.log(`Rendering item ${id}`)
    return (
    <li>
      <label>
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          checked={checked} 
          onChange={() => onChange(id)}
        /> 
        <span>{text}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  )
})

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render(<ItemList />)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5802yc71/6/

Now this obviously will re-render both items every time a checkbox is ticked. The reason is that the `useCallback` will generate a new function reference if the items are changed and thus this will "break" memoization.

Naively we could think to pass an `arePropsEqual` function to the child component and only check if the data has changed, something like:

```js
(prevProps, nextProps) =>
      prevProps.text === nextProps.text &&
      prevProps.checked === nextProps.checked
)
```

Now this will indeed do the trick, *but* the `toggleChecked` function will end up with a stale closure! Reason is that when we select the first check box a new function call will be done on our component and a new `items` state variable will be created in the *new* execution context of the function. Item 2 at this point has access to the `items` variable from the first execution context of the function ... which is empty. Causing the below:

[image: stale closure]

I thought of multiple ways to solve this problem. Originally thought, why don't I take the state entirely out and into a Context. After implementing the context solution I realised that exactly the same problem occurs as the child component still need to get an updated `toggleChecked` function every time the state change and thus it will re-render itself.

Am I right to think that in this scenario I'm better off with a class component or am I missing some trick? As far as I can think since every re-render of the parent will create a new execution context, due to the component being functional, there is no way I can avoid the child components re-rendering as well as they need a callback with a fresh closure.

btw, it's a hard requirement that child component re-renders do *not* happen every time a checkbox is ticked! In the real application rendering the entire list is very costly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this situation you can stabilize `toggleChecked` by using the [callback form of the useState setter](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state). There are scenarios where you have to work harder to ensure that child components don't re-render but this type of thing is common enough that the escape hatch was designed into the hook.

Comment: Doh, you’re right … no idea why I didn’t think of that! :)

Thanks a lot for the quick reply!